# login form on navigation bar in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have created this form for my navigation bar:

```
<form action="/sessions" method="post" class="well form-inline">  
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text" placeholder="Email">  
<input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password" placeholder="Password">  
<label class="checkbox">  
<input type="checkbox"> Remember me  
</label>  
<button name="commit" type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>  
</form>
```

The form is located on the navigation bar, and I have to tell it to go into the `sessions controller` and use the `create` action. How is that done? I searched for days!

......

Comment: The problem is resolved!!! The following correction did the job.

`<input id="user_email" name="email" .... >`

So I only needed to change name="user[email]" to name="email"

Thank you all for trying to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Is this erb? if so, you should use form_for and simply give it the sessions object. See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).

Comment: nice observation. I have it in an erb file, but both form_for and form_tag dont format in the way I want it to. I want this whole code in my navigation bar in order to make a signin block like on facebook for loging in. Beside that, i have multiple models so form_for would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<% form_tag(:controller => "/search", :action => "create", :method => "post") do %>
    # The input fields and other fields
    # <%= input_tag(..params..) %> and so on
<% end %>
```

as mentioned here : [Rails Guides: Multiple Hashes in form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#multiple-hashes-in-form-helper-calls)

Comment: Thank you but I've read that link already. I think you forgot an '=' sign after <% , but that still doesn't solve the problem. I have this code now:

    `<%= form_tag(:controller => "/session", :action => "create", :method => "post") do %>

##########FORM ITEMS#############

     <%= submit_tag "Create my account" , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>`
when i try loging in it gives a routing error: No route matches [POST] "/assets".